# How do I fetch text between two random texts using regular expression

Tags: regex

I am a beginner in regular expression and is now stuck on something for hours. I tried multiple combinations but no success.

My task is to fetch text starting with `Value=` and ends with `};`

**My solutions:**

```
 1. (?<=Value=).*?(.+?)
 2. (?<=Value=).*?
 3. (?<=Value=).*?[^}]
```

These only give me a part of the expected text but not the full text

**Expected Text:**

-

Default

Duty Manager

Professional Employees

Mode Manager

**Test String Below**

```
[Response[attributes={Status=Success, action=Retrieve}; value=[NameList[attributes={PropertyName=Name}; value=[Names[attributes={}; value=[SimplePair[attributes={Key=-, Value=-}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=Preferences, Value=Preferences}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=&DEFAULT_PREFERENCE, Value=Default}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=Profile, Value=Profile}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=Duty Manager, Value=Duty Manager}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=Mode User, Value=Mode User}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=ModeDisplay Profile, Value=Mode Display Profile}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=Mode Manager, Value=Mode Manager}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=Professional Employees, Value=Professional Employees}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=Scheduler, Value=Scheduler}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=Super Access, Value=Super Access}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=keeper, Value=keeper}; value=[]], SimplePair[attributes={Key=Manager, Value=Manager}; value=[]]]]]]]]]}
```

Comment: Why not `(?<=Value=).*?(?=};)`?

Comment: returns a huge string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
(?<=Value=).*?(?=})
```

demo
https://regex101.com/r/J76eaa/1

Explanation of your mistakes:

(?<=Value=).*?(.+?) - this actualy makes no sense at all. "Match any but as less as possible and then match at least one and as less as possible.

(?<=Value=).*? this will match a single character. because you are saying match character as less as possible

(?<=Value=).*?[^}] -  `[^}]` means onecharacter that is NOT } `[}]`is probably what you wanted, which is actually the same as just `}`

Comment: You are a life saver @Predicate. 5 hour dilemma ends now.

Comment: No pro.;) If itworked for you. Upvoting and accepting the answer helps me.;)